# Angular2 Two way bindings doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: firefox, angular, compatibility, 2-way-object-databinding

I am a newee using Angular 2. I developped some forms with Typesript and it is working with Chrome but doesn't with FireFox (version 45).
First of all, I tried the "two way" data bindings with both browsers : Chrome has a correct behavior but FireFox doesn't take in consideration the binding with ngModel (Find my exemple based on 5 min quickstart of angular2).

In addition, the datepicker of bootstrap works well on Chrome and NOT on Firefox.

Thanks in advance,

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Event} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgForm, NgIf, NgFor} from 'angular2/common';


import {Types} from './types';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl:'./app/app.component.html',
    directives : [
      FORM_DIRECTIVES,
      NgForm,
      NgIf,
      NgFor
    ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  field:any;

  types:Array<string> = Types;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.field= {};
  }

  onChange(event:Event) {
    console.log(this.field.type);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Select </label>
<div class="col-sm-4">

<select class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="field.type"
        (change)=onChange($event)
        title="Type">
   <option *ngFor="#t of types">{{ t }}</option>
</select>
</div>

<hr/>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Input </label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <input type="text"
        class="form-control input-sm"
        [(ngModel)]="field.type"
        placeholder="type">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need any of these `    `directives : [
      FORM_DIRECTIVES,
      NgForm,
      NgIf,
      NgFor
    ]` they are provided by default since a while.

Comment: Do you get any error in the browser console? Try changing `field:any;` to `field:any = {};` No need to wait until `ngOnInit()` to initialize it.

Comment: There is no error in the console !

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8030, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6573

Comment: Same problem for me but the other way around: works fine in FF, not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which is **not** very nice :

- HTML file : in the select tag I added `#typeField`
- TS file : I changed the onChange method like below :

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';


import {Types} from './types';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl:'./app/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

  field:any = {};

  types:Array<string> = Types;

  onChange(event:Event, newValue:any) {
    this.field.type = newValue;
    console.log(this.field.type);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Select </label>
<div class="col-sm-4">

<select class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="field.type"
        #typeField
        (change)="onChange($event, typeField.value)"
        title="Type">
   <option *ngFor="#t of types">{{ t }}</option>
</select>
</div>

<hr/>

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Input </label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <input type="text"
        class="form-control input-sm"
        [(ngModel)]="field.type"
        placeholder="type">
</div>
</div>
```